How to customize React Toastify progress bar using tailwindcss?
I am trying to customize the original React-Toastify component using the following code:
  const bgColor = 'bg-[#F6F4E8]';
  const color = 'text-[#1D3124]';
  const progressBarBgColor = '#07bc0c';
  const borderBgColor = 'border-[#1C9099]';

  return (
    <ToastContainer
      toastClassName={() =>
        classNames(
          'relative flex p-2 min-h-10 border rounded-md justify-between overflow-hidden cursor-pointer',
          bgColor,
          color,
          borderBgColor,
        )
      }
      position="top-right"
      autoClose={3000}
      icon={<Icon />}
      closeButton={(props) => <CloseButton closeToast={props.closeToast} />}
      progressStyle={{ background: progressBarBgColor }}
    />
  );

My result was:

It looks great, but I need to customize the "progress bar animate" section that currently appears in light green. I want to achieve this using only inline styles, as I need to be able to change the theme dynamically. I am using Tailwind CSS and would like to continue using it for this customization.
Thanks for your help.

You seem to be already changing the theme of the "progress bar animate" section dynamically  using only inline styles – what's the problem?

Hi @Wongjn, the problem is: this code "progressStyle={{ background: progressBarBgColor }}" only changes the color of the progress bar (green color in the above image) but I want to change the color of the animated progress bar (light green color in the image). You can see that there are 2 green colors used in the progress bar section. So, my goal is to customize them using inline styles. Let me know is all is clear friend.

The progress bar background is rendered by a different element, underneath the progress bar itself, as per the source code:
<div
  className={`${Default.CSS_NAMESPACE}__progress-bar--wrp`}
  data-hidden={isHidden}
>
  <div
    className={`${Default.CSS_NAMESPACE}__progress-bar--bg ${Default.CSS_NAMESPACE}__progress-bar-theme--${theme} ${Default.CSS_NAMESPACE}__progress-bar--${type}`}
  />
  <div
    role="progressbar"
    aria-hidden={isHidden ? 'true' : 'false'}
    aria-label="notification timer"
    className={classNames}
    style={style}
    {...animationEvent}
  />
</div>

From the above code, we can see that we can't pass any style attribute to the element. However, we can see that the CSS uses the --toastify-color-progress-<type> CSS variable to color the background:
.#{$rt-namespace}__progress-bar {
  &-theme--light {
    background: var(--toastify-color-progress-light);
  }
  &-theme--dark {
    background: var(--toastify-color-progress-dark);
  }
  &--info {
    background: var(--toastify-color-progress-info);
  }
  &--success {
    background: var(--toastify-color-progress-success);
  }
  &--warning {
    background: var(--toastify-color-progress-warning);
  }
  &--error {
    background: var(--toastify-color-progress-error);
  }
  &-theme--colored#{&}--info,
  &-theme--colored#{&}--success,
  &-theme--colored#{&}--warning,
  &-theme--colored#{&}--error {
    background: var(--toastify-color-transparent);
  }
}

So we can set this CSS variable value to our own value on the parent and it will inherit down on the progress bar:


const { ToastContainer, toast, Icons } = reactToastify;
const classNames = x => x;
const Icon = Icons.success;
const CloseButton = () => 'CloseButton';

function App() {
  const notify = () => toast.success('This is a magic Toast.');
  
  const bgColor = 'bg-[#F6F4E8]';
  const color = 'text-[#1D3124]';
  const progressBarBgColor = '#07bc0c';
  const borderBgColor = 'border-[#1C9099]';

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <button onClick={notify} className="bg-slate-100">Notify</button>
      <ToastContainer
        toastClassName={() =>
          classNames(
            'relative flex p-2 min-h-10 border rounded-md justify-between overflow-hidden cursor-pointer',
            bgColor,
            color,
            borderBgColor
          )
        }
        position="top-right"
        autoClose={3000}
        icon={<Icon />}
        closeButton={(props) => <CloseButton closeToast={props.closeToast} />}
        progressStyle={{ background: progressBarBgColor }}
        style={{
          '--toastify-color-progress-success': 'red',
        }}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<App/>);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-QVs8Lo43F9lSuBykadDb0oSXDL/BbZ588urWVCRwSIoewQv/Ewg1f84mK3U790bZ0FfhFa1YSQUmIhG+pIRKeg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-6a1107rTlA4gYpgHAqbwLAtxmWipBdJFcq8y5S/aTge3Bp+VAklABm2LO+Kg51vOWR9JMZq1Ovjl5tpluNpTeQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://www.unpkg.com/clsx@2.1.1/dist/clsx.min.js" integrity="sha384-dEq4EUqxSIwObxCTXRGn1G8uU8Dqce+ragCb5MYDS6s+QHC2gaYQLxHklTJLaked" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>window.react = window.React</script>
<script src="https://www.unpkg.com/react-toastify@10.0.5/dist/react-toastify.umd.js" integrity="sha384-axiQ+ovFSlgpLnlT3oGHKz3lWgJJLH9Si9u0aOBilM79dxWHEqsoU4Tmk3AsnfYg" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.unpkg.com/react-toastify@10.0.5/dist/ReactToastify.css" integrity="sha384-4qDaORTdDVMzUks008Hp4k0NNSvc5n/wS3ub2pkl8zdpiYIh6SjCFPecQe8ZZrnq" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>

<body class="bg-slate-950">
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>



Alternatively, you could use a Tailwind class to target and style the progress bar background directly. This would mean you would not need to match the correct type for the --toastify-color-progress-<type> CSS variable:


const { ToastContainer, toast, Icons } = reactToastify;
const classNames = x => x;
const Icon = Icons.success;
const CloseButton = () => 'CloseButton';

function App() {
  const notify = () => toast.success('This is a magic Toast.');
  
  const bgColor = 'bg-[#F6F4E8]';
  const color = 'text-[#1D3124]';
  const progressBarBgColor = '#07bc0c';
  const borderBgColor = 'border-[#1C9099]';

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <button onClick={notify} className="bg-slate-100">Notify</button>
      <ToastContainer
        toastClassName={() =>
          classNames(
            'relative flex p-2 min-h-10 border rounded-md justify-between overflow-hidden cursor-pointer',
            bgColor,
            color,
            borderBgColor
          )
        }
        position="top-right"
        autoClose={3000}
        icon={<Icon />}
        closeButton={(props) => <CloseButton closeToast={props.closeToast} />}
        progressStyle={{ background: progressBarBgColor }}
        className={String.raw`[&_.Toastify\_\_progress-bar--bg]:bg-[--bg]`}
        style={{
          '--bg': 'red',
        }}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<App/>);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-QVs8Lo43F9lSuBykadDb0oSXDL/BbZ588urWVCRwSIoewQv/Ewg1f84mK3U790bZ0FfhFa1YSQUmIhG+pIRKeg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-6a1107rTlA4gYpgHAqbwLAtxmWipBdJFcq8y5S/aTge3Bp+VAklABm2LO+Kg51vOWR9JMZq1Ovjl5tpluNpTeQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://www.unpkg.com/clsx@2.1.1/dist/clsx.min.js" integrity="sha384-dEq4EUqxSIwObxCTXRGn1G8uU8Dqce+ragCb5MYDS6s+QHC2gaYQLxHklTJLaked" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>window.react = window.React</script>
<script src="https://www.unpkg.com/react-toastify@10.0.5/dist/react-toastify.umd.js" integrity="sha384-axiQ+ovFSlgpLnlT3oGHKz3lWgJJLH9Si9u0aOBilM79dxWHEqsoU4Tmk3AsnfYg" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.unpkg.com/react-toastify@10.0.5/dist/ReactToastify.css" integrity="sha384-4qDaORTdDVMzUks008Hp4k0NNSvc5n/wS3ub2pkl8zdpiYIh6SjCFPecQe8ZZrnq" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>

<body class="bg-slate-950">
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>




Thank so much @Wongjn, it works perfectly. And I can learn how to modify existing Toastify CSS properties reading your code example. It is really appreciated friend.
